# Jquery validation error typeError for file's extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html form has some inputs for validation:

```
        <form role="form" id="addForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userName">User name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Enter user name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" required id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" type="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="homePage">Home page</label>
                <input class="form-control"  id="homePage" name="homePage" placeholder="Enter home page" type="url"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="text">Text</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" required id="text" rows="8" name="text" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea>
            </div>

            <a href ="javascript:void(0);" id="captchaLink"><img  id="secPic" src="sec_pic.php" alt="secret code"></a>


            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="captcha">Captcha</label>
                <input class="form-control" required id="captcha"  name="captcha" placeholder="Enter captcha"/>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="userIp" id="userIp" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="userBrowser" id="userBrowser" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?>">

            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="userFile">File</label>
                <input name="userFile" id="userFile" type="file"  />
            </div>


            <button name="submit" id="submit" value="" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block">Add a news</button>
        </form>
```

For validation I use Jquery validation plugin. 
And my js is:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please use only a-z0-9_-");


    jQuery.validator.addMethod("fileSize", function (val, element) {

        var size = element.files[0].size;
        console.log(size);

        if (size > 100000)// checks the file more than 100 kb
        {
            console.log("returning false");
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log("returning true");
            return true;
        }

    }, "File size should not be larger than 100 kb");



    $("#addForm").validate({
        rules:{
            userName:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 10,
                lettersonly:true
            },
            email:{
                required: true,
                email:true
            },
            homePage:{
                required:true,
                url: true
            },
            text:{
                required:true,
                lettersonly:true
            },
            captcha:{
                required:true,
                remote: {
                    url:"check-captcha.php",
                    type: "post"
                }
            },
            userFile:{
                required: true,
               // extension: "txt"
            }
        },
        messages:{
            userName:{
                required: "This field is required",
                minlength: "Name must be at least 2 characters",
                maxlength: "Maximum number of characters - 10"
            },
            captcha: {
                remote: " NO!"
            }
        }
    });
```

When I add to userFile **extension: "txt"**  I get error:
TypeError: t.validator.methods[a] is undefined

How can I solve my problem? without extension my code works

Answer (score 0):

You must include the file "additional-methods.min.js".